# Is it possible to join() threads and start the other threads then? ( KOTLIN )

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety

Im trying to count to 200000 in four threads, I want to count with the first both
threads to 200_000 and subtract after counting of the both first.
I know I can do it with join, but when im starting join it doesn't count because of the add function (counter++)

It look like this:

```
 val s = Semaphore(1)
   var count = 0

thread{
 repeat(100_000){
   s.acquire()
   add()
   s.release()
println("${Thread.currentThread().name} :$count")
}
}
  thread{
 repeat(100_000){
   s.acquire()
   subtract()
   s.release()
println("${Thread.currentThread().name} :$count")
}
}

fun add(){
count++
}
fun subtract(){
count--
}
```

The functions do only add/subtract for the counter variable above the Threads

Comment: It's not clear from your description what the problem is. What is the code in your `add()` function? Is it incrementing a variable? Are you using synchronization? If multiple threads are incrementing the same variable, some increments will be lost because they happen at the same time. What's the point in starting a thread, joining it, and starting another thread, instead of just doing all the sequential tasks in the same thread?

Comment: the function add() 
do just : count++

Comment: And what is the problem? Your code above doesn't have any `join()` calls. You need to describe your wanted/expected behavior and the actual behavior for us to be able to help.

Comment: I want to count to 200k first with the both adding threads
and then subtract to zero with the other two

Comment: Do you understand about atomic changes and volatile variables? You still haven’t shared your code I asked for so I can’t tell you what’s missing.

Comment: val s = Semaphore(1)
val count = 0
thread{
 repeat(100_000){
   s.acquire()
   add()
  println("${Thread.currentThread().name} :$count")
   s.release()
}
}

fun add(){
count++
}
fun subtract(){
count--
}

Comment: Ive edited the question here

Comment: I give up. This still isn't the actual code you're running, because you only have one of each thread, you're not joining them, the `count` is a `val`, and I can't see what's in a function and what isn't.